# missing d3dx9.lib file in windows 10 sdk for ARM

Tags: visual-studio, arm, directx

I am porting my Windows directX application from X86 device to ARM in VS2017. But I could not find some DirectX library files(d3dx9.lib) for ARM in VS built-in Windows 10 SDK. The offical DirectX SDK (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812) does not support ARM. Where can i find ARM version of these library files?

Comment: There is none...

Comment: D3DX is deprecated for quite a time https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So d3dx is deprecated, thanks to Simon and Jake.